# Nhibernate: Retrieving column names from CreateSqlQuery

Tags: nhibernate

When using CreateSqlQuery, is it possible to retrieve an ordered list of the returned column names?
Using .List only returns a list of the object values, not the column aliases.

Answer (score 12):

If you apply an `IResultTransformer` to your query via `SetResultTransformer()`, it will be called with two lists containing column names and values.

There are several existing transformers in namespace **NHibernate.Transform**, such as:

- `AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer` Creates a [map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx) from column names to values for each row.
- `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` Creates an object of the nominated type per row and sets its properties with the value from the column of the same name.
- `ToListResultTransformer` Returns a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) of values for each row.

Comment: For those who needs an example, here's one which worked to me: `.CreateSQLQuery("...").SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer())`

Comment: if I need to get just table name?